# How can I serialize Microsoft.Kinect.ColorImageFrame?

Tags: c#, wcf, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm working on project to provide some Kinect functions as WCF services. I'm having a problem with some classes such as ColorImageFrame which cannot be serialized. I was thinking to inherit from it and make it "Serializable" but the problem is ColorImageFrame class is a sealed class. Any ideas?

Here a simple example of what I want to do; I'm not sure if I'm doing it in the right way.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IKinectTools
{     
    [OperationContract]
    ColorImageFrame getVideoStream(); 
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class KinectTools : IKinectTools
{
    KinectSensor sensor;
    ColorImageFrame videoData = null;

    void sensor_ColorFrameReady(object sender, ColorImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        videoData = e.OpenColorImageFrame();

    }
    public ColorImageFrame getVideoStream()
    {          
        return videoData;
    }            
}
```

I just want to build a WCF service to make the video stream available to the clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a property, getter convert your ColorImageFrame to byte[].

byte[] can be serialized !

Use this method to obtain byte datas :

ColorImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(Byte[])

sample :

```
public byte[] ColorImageFrameData
{
    get
    {
        byte[] ret= new byte[_colorImageFrame.PixelDataLength]; 
        _colorImageFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(ret);
        return ret;
    }
}
```